# Google reauthentication: The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on my app, where it is possible to log in via Google. When the user wants to change email or password, firebase requires to reauthenticate user. And here is my question - how to detect if the user has selected correct account when logging in? This screen is different from the one at regular signup (https://imgur.com/a/jIJXBYY).
Currently, selecting a different account crashes the entire app with error: Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/user-mismatch] The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user.

Here is the code that is responsible for reauthentication:

```
try {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.reauthenticateWithProvider(GoogleAuthProvider());
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
```